# Are the solutions of $f(x+h)=f(x)f(h)$of the form $a^x$ even if we consider discontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, examples-counterexamples

Let $$f(x):\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $$$$$$and$$f(x+h)=f(x)f(h)$$

If $f(x)$ is a continuous function  then we can prove all solutions for ($f(x)$ not  equal to zero at any point) are of the form  $a^x$ .(Where $a^x$ is defined using sequences ) by simply using properties of $f(x)$ and continuity

> But is the result still true if we also consider $f$ not continuous and ($f(x)$ not equal to zero at any point) or is there a counter-example?

---

This function can be constant and the constant must be $1$ but that is the only constant value the function can achieve and since the constant function on $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$is continuous the previous result  will work .
If we can prove that such a function must be either monotonically increasing everywhere or monotonically decreasing everywhere if it is not $1$
Then we can use the theorem that a function from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$that is monotonically increasing must be continuous somewhere which for this function due to the functional equation would imply the function is continuous everywhere and we would have proved the question using the previous result .
Q: Can the existence of nosuch function be somehow proven by using monotonicity (or some other way )or is there a counter-example?

Comment: Fix the big typo.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Edited thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, $f(x)$ for some $x$ implies $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. Excluding this case the question  can be translated to Cauchy's equation : $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$ by taking logarithm. Here are some facts about $g$: If $g$ is Borel measurable (in particular if it is monotone) then $g(x)=cx$ for some constant $c$.  But there exist non-measurable solution so  of this equation. [Proof of the existence of such functions requires Axiom of Choice].

Hence $f(x)=a^{x}$ need not be true in general (take $f(x)=e^{g(x)})$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110731/discussion-on-answer-by-kavi-rama-murthy-are-the-solutions-of-fxhfxfho).

Answer (score 1):

**No.** There exist non-vanishing such functions which are not exponential.

First observe that, if $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$, for all $x,y$, and $f(x)=\exp\big(g(x)\big)$, then $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$, for all $x,y$.

To obtain an additive $g$, i.e., $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$, for all $x,y$, which is not of the form $g(x)=cx$, we need to use Zorn's Lemma, and in particular, the fact that $\mathbb R$ possesses a Hamel basis, as a linear space over $\mathbb Q$. In other words, there exists a $B\subset \mathbb R$, such that:

Every $x\in\mathbb R$ can be written, in a unique way as a linear combination of elements of $B$ with rational coefficients. That is, for every $x\in\mathbb R$, there exist unique $b_1,\ldots,b_n\in B,$ and $q_1,\ldots,q_n\in\mathbb Q$, such that
$$
x=q_1b_1+\cdots+q_nb_n.
$$

Now, for every set of $c_i$'s in $\mathbb R$, the function
$$
g(x)=q_1q(b_1)+\cdots+q_ng(b_n)=q_1c_1+\cdots+q_nc_n,
$$
is additive, i.e., $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$, and the coresponding $f$, i.e., $f(x)=e^{g(x)}$ satisfies
$$
g(x+y)=g(x)g(y).
$$
If the $c_i$'s are not proportional to the $b_i$'s, then $f$ is not continuous and hence not exponential. For example, say $g(b_i)=c_i$, $i=1,2$, and $b_1c_2-b_2c_1\ne 0$. Say $c_1\ne 0$, and $\{q_n\}\in \mathbb  Q$, so that $q_n\to b_1/b_2$. Then
$$
f(q_nb_2)=q_nc_2\to b_1c_2/b_2
$$
while
$$
q_n b_2\to b_2\cdot b_1/b_2=b_1\quad\text{and}\quad f(b_1)=c_1\ne b_1c_2/b_2.
$$

Comment: Why if the $c_{i}$ are not equal then f is not exponential? and why g(x) has a $g(b_{n}$)?

Comment: It was a mistake.

Comment: See my corrected answer.

Comment: This requires axiom of choice is that correct?

Comment: Yes it does require the Axiom of Choice

Comment: It is accepted. Without the Axiom of Choice we do not know that: Every linear space has a basis.

Comment: The Axiom of Choice is equivalent to Zorn's Lemma which is equivalent to the existence of Hamel Basis. Without the Axiom of Choice we can not conclude whether there exists or not such a function. But, today everybody accepts the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: AC is independent of the ZF, but without it we would have serious problems: Proof of Hahn-Banach, Existence of non-measurable sets, Existence of orthonormal basis, countable union of countable sets is countable, etc.

Comment: (+1) I wonder if there is a proof which does not use any choice (fully in ZF)...